# why PyObject* can point to any object in python?

Tags: python, c

In python's source code, there are some macro definitions like this:

```c
#define PyObject_HEAD    \
    int ob_refcnt;       \
    struct _typeobject *ob_type;


#define PyObject_VAR_HEAD  \
    PyObject_HEAD          \
    int ob_size; 


typedef struct _object {  
    PyObject_HEAD  
} PyObject;    

typedef struct _object {  
    PyObject_HEAD   
    long ob_ival;   
} PyIntObject;   

typedef struct {   
    PyObject_VAR_HEAD   
} PyVarObject;
```

The question is, why PyObject* can point to each object(such as PyIntObject, PyVarObject) in python?

Comment: Are there some backslashes missing in the macro definitions?

Comment: Does it look correct now after I edited it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each struct for the different types of Python object has an instance of `PyObject_HEAD` as its first member (or the first member of its first member, and so on).

This member sub-object is guaranteed to be located at the same address as the full object.

The `PyObject_HEAD*` points at that member sub-object, but could be cast to the full type once `ob_type` has been inspected to work out what the full type is.

This trick isn't unique to CPython -- it's often used to implement a limited kind of inheritance in C. Basically you model the "is a X" relationship by "has a X at the start of".

Comment: In [this](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#c.PyObject), it mentioned Py_REFCNT, Py_TYPE and Py_SIZE macros, but no #define's like Py_REFCNT(x) (x->ob_type). Can someone show their source code or the link to it?

Answer (score 2):

Because `PyObject_HEAD` is ALWAYS the first struct member not affected by the concrete underlying type. The pointer will ofcourse get casted.