# How does python compute the hash of a tuple

Tags: python, hash, tuples

In python, if I have a tuple with many elements, is its hash calculated from its elements' `id`s or its elements' content?

In this example,

```
a = (1, [1,2])
hash(a)
```

It errors out saying list is unhashable. So I guess it's not computed by id, or probably there is a check on whether the element is mutable.

Now see this example

```
class A: pass
a0 = A()
ta = (1, a0)
hash(ta)  # -1122968024
a0.x = 20
hash(ta)  # -1122968024
```

Here it turns out the hash of `ta` does not change with the modification of its element, i.e., `a0`. So maybe `a0`'s id is used for the hash calculation? Is `a0` somehow considered as immutable? How does python know if a type is mutable?

Now consider this case

```
b = (1, 2)
id(b)  # 3980742764
c = (1, 2)
id(c)  # 3980732588
tb = (1, b)
tc = (1, c) 
hash(tb)  # -1383040070
hash(tc)  # -1383040070
```

It seems the content of `b` and `c` are used for the hash calculation.

How should I understand these examples?

Comment: short answer is that `hash(tb) == hash(tc)` because although `id(a)` and `id(b)` are not equal, `hash(a)` and `hash(b)` are the same.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> If I have a tuple with many elements, is its hash calculated from its elements' ids or its elements' content?

Neither. It is calculated on the basis of the hashes of these elements, not their "contents" (values/attributes), nor IDs.

---

### The basics: why hashes are used the way they are

Take a look at [this paragraph](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable) in python's documentation glossary.

Whether something is hashable or not, and how it is hashed, depends on the implementation of its `__hash__()` method. By itself, Python has no idea about mutability of an object. It's the implementation that is expected to provide appropriate mechanisms and avoid pitfalls.

A hash is useful in identification of objects. For example, it speeds up data retrieval from a `dict`, identifying the arbitrary value of a key by a single numerical value from a finite interval - the key's hash.

**A hash should remain unchanged throughout the lifetime of the object.** Otherwise, one object could map to two different values in a `dict`, or be included into a `set` twice, as soon as its hash changes.

It's not enough to compare two objects by their hashes: at the end of the day, you may still need to perform equality checks, [because there may be a collision between the hashes of two different objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45795637/what-exactly-is-hash-collision). That's why **hashable objects are required to have `__eq__()` implemented.**

This ties back to the mutability: if a hashable object mutates such that it changes equality comparisons *with hashables*, especially the ones with the same hash - it breaks the contract, and may result in the same weirdness a mutating hash would. **Hashable objects should not mutate comparisons between themselves.**

**Hashable objects that are equal to each other *should* have the same hash.** This is a general contract that makes everything else simpler - it's natural to assume `x == y` implies that both `x` and `y` map to the same value in a `dict`.

---

### Hash of a tuple

Consider your first example. The `tuple` hashes itself on the basis of its elements, while its second element, the `list`, doesn't have a hash at all - the `__hash__` method is not implemented for it. And so the `tuple.__hash__` method fails.

That's why a `tuple` with a `list` object inside of it is not hashable. As you can see, it is therefore also incorrect to say, that a `tuple` hash is based on the IDs of its elements.

Notice, that if the `list` was hashable here, and the hash was based on its elements, changing them would change the hash of the outer `tuple`, breaking the contract.

---

### Why my custom class doesn't require a `__hash__()`?

Let's have a look at [python data model documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__), and what it has to say on the topic:

> User-defined classes have `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` methods by default; with them, all objects compare unequal (except with themselves) and `x.__hash__()` returns an appropriate value such that `x == y` implies both that `x is y` and `hash(x) == hash(y)`.

Put simply, the default implementation compares objects *identity*, which has nothing to do with object *attributes*. That's why you can change the values "inside" the object of your custom class without changing its hash.

That's also why you don't have to define `__hash__()` for your classes - python does it for you in this case.

In this regard you're right - the default (*CPython's*) implementation of the hashing function for custom classes relies on the [`id()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) of an object (and not on the values "inside" of it). It is an implementation detail, and it differs between Python versions.

In more recent versions of Python, the relation between `hash()` and `id()` involves randomization. This prevents some forms of [denial of service attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack), where creating arbitrary hash collisions could significantly slow down web applications. See [PEP-456](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0456/).

---

### How does it actually hash itself?

While the details are quite complicated and probably involve some advanced math, the implementation of the hash function for tuple objects is written in C, and can be seen [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/tupleobject.c#L348) (see `static Py_hash_t tuplehash(PyTupleObject *v)`).

The calculation involves XORing a constant with the hashes of each of the tuple's elements. The line responsible for hashing of the elements is this one:

```
y = PyObject_Hash(*p++);
```

---

So, to answer your original question: it does a bunch of XOR hokus-pocus with the **hashes of each of its elements**. Whether or not the contents and attributes of these elements are considered depends on their specific hash functions.

Comment: An interesting discussion about how this function evolved: [Hash collisions for tuples](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2018-September/379989.html). It was a simple `x = (1000003 * x) ^ y`, "_but changed to the heart of the current scheme to address Source Forge bug #942952_" (the problem was with `hash( (X, (X, Y)) ) == hash(Y)`), "_So the complications were added for a reason, to address the showed-up-in-real-life pathological cases_"

Answer (score 9):

The core contract of hashing is that **equal objects have equal hashes**. In particular, hashing does not directly care about mutability or mutation; it only cares about **mutation that affects equality comparisons**.

---

Your first tuple is unhashable because mutating the nested list would change how the tuple behaves in equality comparisons.

Mutating `a0` in your second example doesn't affect the hash of the tuple because it doesn't affect equality comparisons. `a0` is still only equal to itself, and its hash is unchanged.

`tb` and `tc` in your third example have equal hashes because they are equal tuples, regardless of whether their elements are the same objects.

---

This all means that tuples cannot (directly) use `id` for hashes. If they did, equal tuples with distinct but equal elements could hash differently, violating the contract of hashing. Without special-casing element types, the only things tuples can use to compute their own hashes are their elements' hashes, so tuples base their hashes on their elements' hashes.

Answer (score 5):

The answer to the question "Is the tuple's hash calculated based on the identity or the value?" is: Neither.

The correct answer is that the tuple's hash is calculated from the elements' hashes. How *those* hashes are calculated is (more or less) irrelevant.

An easy way to prove this is to see what happens when you put a list into a tuple:

```
>>> hash( (1, 2) )
3713081631934410656
>>> hash( (1, []) )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Because lists aren't hashable, a tuple containing a list isn't hashable either.

---

Let's take a closer look at this example you brought:

```
class A: pass
a0 = A()
ta = (1, a0)
hash(ta)  # -1122968024
a0.x = 20
hash(ta)  # -1122968024
```

Why doesn't setting `a0.x = 20` affect the tuple's hash? Well, if we modify this code to output the hash of `a0`, you'll see that setting `a0.x = 20` has no effect on `a0`'s hash value:

```
a0 = A()
print(hash(a0))  # -9223363274645980307
a0.x = 20
print(hash(a0))  # -9223363274645980307
```

The reason for this is that python implements a default hash function for you. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> User-defined classes have `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` methods by default;
>   with them, all objects compare unequal (except with themselves) and
>   `x.__hash__()` returns an appropriate value such that `x == y` implies
>   both that `x is y` and `hash(x) == hash(y)`.

The default hash function ignores the object's attributes and calculates the hash based on the object's id. No matter what changes you make to `a0`, its hash will always stay the same. (Though it is possible to define a custom hash function for instances of your `A` class by implementing a custom [`__hash__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) method.)

---

Addendum: The reason why lists aren't hashable is because they're mutable. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__):

> If a class defines mutable objects and implements an `__eq__()` method,
>   it should not implement `__hash__()`, since the implementation of
>   hashable collections requires that a key’s hash value is immutable (if
>   the object’s hash value changes, it will be in the wrong hash bucket).

Lists fall into this category.

Answer (score 2):

the hash of a `tuple` is based on the *contents*, not on the _id_s of the tuples. And the hashes are computed recursively: if one element isn't hashable (like a `list` element), then the tuple itself isn't hashable.

That's perfectly normal that if `a` and `b` are tuples and `a == b`, then `hash(a) == hash(b)` (if hashes can be computed of course), even if `a is not b`.

(on the contrary `hash(a) == hash(b)` doesn't mean that `a == b`)

The information conveyed by `is` is often not very useful, because of python object interning for example.

Comment: `a = b` (a is b; same object) is stronger than (implies) `a == b` (same value implies `hash(a)=hash(b)`), but not vice versa (maybe a different object/instance). Also, tuples being immutable doesn't necessarily mean hashable. For instance, (1,2,[3,4]) is a tuple, but unhashable, it fails to be a key for dictionary or a set member.

Answer (score 0):

> Though it is possible to define a custom hash function for instances of your A class by implementing a custom **hash** method.

Below is an example code that shows id() is used in the default case and an [overriding hash method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38430277/python-class-hash-method-and-set).

```
def printHash(a0):
    print(hex(id(a0)), hex(hash(a0)))

class   A:
    def __init__(self, x=10):
        self.x = x
print("Using default hash()")
a0 = A();   printHash(a0)
a0.x = 20;  printHash(a0)

class   A2:
    def __init__(self, x=10):
        self.x = x
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.x)
print("User defined hash()")
a0 = A2();  printHash(a0)
a0.x = 20;  printHash(a0)
```

Output:

```
Using default hash()
0x1b42089bd00 0x1b42089bd0
0x1b42089bd00 0x1b42089bd0
User defined hash()
0x1b42089bc70 0xa
0x1b42089bc70 0x14
```

Since [PyObject/PyObject_HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736762/why-pyobject-can-point-to-any-object-in-python) is 16 bytes long, that may be why id is 16-byte
aligned and hash() drops the last hex address byte to randomize it.